# Pass Codeigniter input date as mysql date formate

Tags: mysql, date, codeigniter-3

I am trying insert birth day from codeigniter form to mysql database as mysql date format, But i am getting like this format "06/27/2018".

My model as below

```
$birth_day = date('Y-m-d'); /* i want in this format*/
$birth_day = $this->input->post("b_day");

$data['b_day'] = $birth_day;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$birth_day = $this->input->post("b_day");
$data['b_day'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($birth_day));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` to change in `Y-m-d` format like this :

Working demo : https://eval.in/1027380

```
$date_from_form = '06/27/2018';

/* Or do like this for post input
   $date_from_form = $this->input->post("b_day");
*/

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date_from_form);
$birth_day  =  $date->format('Y-m-d');
//echo $birth_day;

$data['b_day'] = $birth_day;
```

Program Output

```
2018-06-27
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: that answer you accepted as green its ok that is pretty simple i can also give you the same but given my answer with a reason just because of it pls see it https://eval.in/1029642 ,  you can not solve it with simple `strtotime` you have to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`